# K-means clustering for one class classification

Tags: python, classification, keras, k-means

I want to know if I can use the k-means clustering algorithm for a one class classification (as in the case of one class SVM), which means I have data for 2 classes, and I labelled only the one class that I used for training?

Comment: Can you clarify what means that you only labelled one?

Comment: knowing that I have 2 classes(positive/negative), I mean that I'm doing the training phase with only positive classe (labeled data) and while testing I'll use the two classes. I want the model could detect the negative data.

Comment: Why don't you have the two classes in both sets?

Comment: the project , I'm working on,  aims to test a behavioral approach, which means learning only positive behavior to detect negative one. I should test more than one classifier. I have tested it using one-class SVM, but I'm not sure that it's possible using kMC because it's unsupervised learning algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

- The K-means algorithm has the capacity of retrieving which are the "boundaries" your data has for knowing the only-class, is possible that you don't find the only-class boundaries to be the same boundaries your k-means algorithm found. This is the risk of comparing k-means with the one class classification: Clustering can be looking different things from one class classification.
- This answer may guide you to another solution.

[How to perform model selection for One-Class Classification?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11838/how-to-perform-model-selection-for-one-class-classification?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

A Gaussian Mixture Model can be seen as a generalization of k-means, with soft (probabilistic) cluster assignments rather than hard ones. It can be, and often is, used in a one-class setting. It allows for multiple Gaussian components and for non-spherical shapes of clusters, which can be an advantage with many datasets.
But if one restricts to single components with spherical covariance matrix, it is very similar to k-means.